# Excel PivotTable : Calculated Field / Item for Period Comparison

Tags: excel-2007

If I have a PivotTable in Excel 2007 with a date field. I understand that I can group the date by day, month or even year using Group Field (Years & Months).

If I combine with product perspective, the PivotTable may look like this

```
Sum of Sales_Total   |   Column Labels
Row Labels           |   PRODUCT-001 | PRODUCT-002 | Grand Total
- 2006               |          2000 |        1500 |        3500
   Jan               |          1700 |         800 |        2500
   Feb               |           300 |         700 |        1000
- 2007               |          1000 |        1500 |        2500
   Jan               |           700 |         800 |        1500
   Feb               |           300 |         700 |        1000
- 2008               |           600 |         700 |        1300
   Jan               |           600 |         700 |        1300
```

Now, what I want to do is to compare Jan 2008 - Jan 2006 and Jan 2007 - Jan 2006. Something like this :

```
                     | Column Labels
                     | PRODUCT-001    |                   |  ...
Row Labels           | Sum of Sales   | Sum of Last Sales | 
- 2006               |          2000  |                   | 
   Jan               |          1700  |                   | 
   Feb               |           300  |                   | 
- 2007               |          1000  |        2000       | 
   Jan               |           700  |        1700       | 
   Feb               |           300  |         300       | 
- 2008               |           600  |        1000       | 
   Jan               |           600  |         700       |
```

Is it possible ? If so, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the month higher in the column hierarchy, this way you'll get

```
Jan
   2008
   2007
   2006
 Feb
   2008
   2007
   2006
```

Comment: Hi, that would do the trick. But I'm not expecting layout like that. Still prefer Year -> Month hierarchy.